# map a key to open Tagbar and NERDTree at the same time

Tags: key-bindings, split, plugin-nerdtree, plugin-tagbar

I want to be editing a file like this:

```
---------------
|             |
|             |
|    DOC      |
|             |
|             |
|             |
---------------
```

And then press <kbd>F5</kbd> and open NERDTree and Tagbar like this:

```
---------------
|    |        |
|NERD|   DOC  |
|TREE|        |
|----|        |
|TAG |        |
| BAR|        |
---------------
```

The commands I use to open NERDTree and Tagbar are `:NERDTreeTabsToggle` and `:TagbarToggle`

If this can't be done, then how can I just open tagbar below or above NERDTree?

Comment: `nnoremap <F5> :NERDTreeTabsToggle <bar> TagbarToggle<cr>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|`. See `:help :bar`:

> '|' can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one line. If you want to use '|' in an argument, precede it with '\'.

In your case it would be:

```
nnoremap <f5> :NERDTreeTabsToggle | :TagbarToggle<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consulting the documentation of these plugins, you can find out how to tweak the position of their buffers. I achieved what you want as follows:

```
let g:tagbar_left = 1
let g:tagbar_vertical = 25
let NERDTreeWinPos = 'left'
nnoremap <f5> :NERDTreeToggle <CR> :TagbarToggle <CR>
```

Note: `:NERDTreeTabsToggle` is not part of NERDTree itself, as it seems. Are you using [this plugin](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs)? I don't know if it works the same.